# WCF Routing with Message Security

Tags: wcf, wcf-security, wcf-routing

I have a WCF service with Message Security **Authentication**.

I want to set up a routing service for Load Balancing.

For some reason it doesn't work, I've enabled includeExceptionDetailInFaults to see exceptions, so in the client I see:

> The client certificate is not provided. Specify a client certificate
>   in ClientCredentials.

It seems that the certificate isn't forwarded from router->service.

Currently the client/router/service is on the same machine, so I have all the certificates, but if I deploy them on a different machine will the Router have to have the private keys?

In addition, if I want to establish a non-secured connection between the router and service (offload the security), how can I provide the Identity of the caller?

EDIT : 
For all Client/Router(both server&client)/Server the security configured the same :

```
            <security mode="Message">
                <message clientCredentialType="Certificate" negotiateServiceCredential="false"
                    algorithmSuite="Default" establishSecurityContext="false" />
            </security>
```

Comment: Can you show the 3 config files?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This blog post explains that Microsoft didn't support this scenarion-

http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/applisec/archive/2011/12/12/wcf-routing-and-message-security.aspx

Comment: This answer is from 5 years ago. I hope that Microsoft will fix their blog.

Answer (score 2):

There are many articles that says Microsoft didn't support this scenario and it is true.

[This article explains how to write your own custom solution to provide security to all client/router/service.](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/458473/Custom-Authentication-and-Security-for-Routing-Ser)

Answer (score 1):

> The client certificate is not provided. Specify a client certificate in ClientCredentials.

I have seen this error when the service certificate doesn't match the host domain name.

If you are still seeing this issue can you post some of your configuration entries?

Comment: The certificate doesn't match the host name. I use 'localhost' or IP now. But it still should work .. is it a known bug?

Comment: you could try [WinHttpCertCfg.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384088(v=vs.85).aspx) to see if the certificate is setup correctly with the necessary permissions to use the key.

Comment: I don't think that this will help, I run the applications as Administrator so I should have sufficient permissions.

Answer (score 0):

1) As first try to set certificate in the client side by code.

```
ChannelFactory<IService1> factory = 
             new ChannelFactory<IService1>("Service1_Endpoint");
factory.Credentials.ServiceCertificate.SetDefaultCertificate(
             System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.StoreLocation.CurrentUser,
             System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.StoreName.My,
             System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509FindType.FindBySubjectName,
             "<SeriveCerificateName>");
```

If you really have problem with certificate you promptly get exception at the application startup.

2) If there is no exception then check thumbprints of the service certificate on both sides.